# If a ligature/digraph has separate collation order, should it be considered different from constituent letters?

Tags: unicode, string, locale, characters

There are many digraphs and ligatures in common use like ß, w, ﬃ, ﬆ, æ, ǆ, ch etc.

Some of these are completely different from its constituents. For eg, search for `u` in a string containing `w` should return false, similar is the case for `s` and `ß`.

But some of them are just glyph ligatures. For eg, search for `f` in a string containing `ﬃ` should return true, similar is the case for `s` and `ﬆ`.

But what about Icelandic `æ` or Slovak `ǆ` or Czech `ch`? All these have status of letter in their alphabet, and have a different collation order. Now, if I search for `a`, `d`, `c` respectively, should they return false? If they return false, they are deceiving what eyes see. If they return true, then what's the point in giving them the status of letter?

Is there an other internationally accepted standard regarding this?

Comment: [Unicode Collation Algorithm](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/). Note that `æ`=(U+00E6,  *Latin Small Letter Ae*), `ǆ`=(U+01C6,  *Latin Small Letter Dz With Caron*) with compatibility decomposition (`d` (U+0064,  *Latin Small Letter D*) + `z` (U+007A,  *Latin Small Letter Z*) + `̌` (U+030C,  *Combining Caron*)) and digraphs (e.g. `ch` in Spanish or Czech sorting) are noticed in the linked document as well… See also [Unicode normalization forms](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15).

Comment: @JosefZ I know that, for collation, Czech `ch` acts as single character. But I'm not sure for string search. For example, word 'chemie' comes after `h` in dictionary according to collation rules. Now, if search for `c` in 'chemie' should the search algorithm return `true` or `false`?

Comment: String search where? It depends on implementation. For instance, in PowerShell 5.1 and `(Get-Culture).Name` -> `cs-CZ` I get `'chemie'.StartsWith('c')` -> `False` and `'chemie'.Contains('c')` -> `True`. Poweshell 7.1 (`pwsh`) gives the same results however there is implemented *comparison type* as follows: `'chemie'.Contains('c', 'CurrentCulture')` -> `False`.

Comment: @JosefZ wow, that's weird. Isn't there a standard for that? Can implementations define whatever they want? If I was a Czech and this is the case with software, it would be very hard.

Comment: I'm Czech (and I consider myself an expert on the _Czech language_) and I have no problem with digraph `ch` - it's considered a regular *letter* in linguistics however *two characters* everywhere incl. typing (there is no `ch` key on a keyboard): note that `'chemie'.ToCharArray() -join '_'` returns `c_h_e_m_i_e`. So I don't care about this ambiguity - except pure linguistic application…

Comment: @JosefZ In that case, why `'chemie'.StartsWith('c')` is `False`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135638/discussion-between-josefz-and-sourav-kannantha-b).